# My esp01 code keeps on erasing after reboot

Tags: esp8266, blynk

I am uploading a simple Blynk cloud example code to control a led on GPIO2 of my esp01 board.

```cpp
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID ""
#define BLYNK_DEVICE_NAME ""

#define BLYNK_FIRMWARE_VERSION        "0.1.0"

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
//#define BLYNK_DEBUG

#define APP_DEBUG

// Uncomment your board, or configure a custom board in Settings.h
//#define USE_SPARKFUN_BLYNK_BOARD
//#define USE_NODE_MCU_BOARD
//#define USE_WITTY_CLOUD_BOARD
//#define USE_WEMOS_D1_MINI

#include "BlynkEdgent.h"

BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
 int pinValue = param.asInt();
  Serial.println("Value Change");
  digitalWrite(2,pinValue); 
}
void setup()
{
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  BlynkEdgent.begin();
}

void loop() {
  BlynkEdgent.run();
}
```

when I run it for the first time it works flawlessly, it gets configured easily with Blynk app and i am able to control the led.
but, when I reboot my esp01 it does not store the credentials and again starts the code from beginning!!
I think I am not able to get out of programming mode.
Please help me out !!
Thanks

Comment: try to add `WiFi.persistent();` and `WiFi.setAutoConnect();`. it was the default until esp8266 Arduino version 3, but now both are off by default

Comment: @Juraj but it works fine for my nodemcu? So do you think it is the real prob?